# switch for type string for java 1.6

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have the following code and I'm wondering if there is a way to use a switch block instead of a bunch of if/else statements. I know that Java supports strings in switch blocks as of Java 1.7 but I'm still working with Java 1.6:

```
} else if (typeName.equals("Boolean")) {

            return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean((String) memberValue));

        } else if (typeName.equals("Double")) {

            return new SwitchInputType<Double>(new Double((String) memberValue));

        } else if (typeName.equals("Int32"))
```

Comment: @TGMCians-but there is a way to use something else that can do the job,maybe static (not sure how to do that)

Comment: -1 for not doing basic research. I just googled it and I can see there are number of similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could even make the `enum` do it for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String typeName = "Boolean";
    String memberValue = "memberValue";
    SwitchInputType type = Type.valueOf(typeName).makeType(memberValue);
}

enum Type {
    Boolean {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean(memberValue));
        }
    },
    Double {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Double>(new Double(memberValue));
        }
    }, 
    Int32 {
        SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Integer>(new Integer(memberValue));
        }
    };

    // All must do this.
    abstract SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue);
}

static class SwitchInputType<T> {
    public SwitchInputType(Object o) {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a more object-oriented approach.

Comment: Thanks but the code doesn't enter to  abstract SwitchInputType makeType(String memberValue); since the return statment and i guess that is the reason that the type doesnt have really type?do you know how can i fix that ?

Comment: @JohnJerrby - sorry I don't understand your problem. It cannot enter the `abstract` method, there is no code there. The `abstract` method is there to make sure all `enum`s implement that method. The result of the `valueOf` call is an `enum` which has a `makeType` method which is then called with the `String` parameter. Add some print statements and run the code - you will understand.

Answer (score 7):

As your strings are all valid identifiers, you could create an enumeration with those strings as the item labels, use [Enum.valueOf(Class, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) (or the similar `valueOf(String)` method that will be created in your enumeration class) to convert to a member of the enumeration type, and then switch based on that...

Example:

```
enum TypeName { Boolean, Double, Int32 }

switch (TypeName.valueOf(typeName)) {
   case Boolean: // ...
   case Double: // ...
   case Int32: // ...
}
```

Comment: @Jules- cam you  provide an example please?

Comment: Quick example added -- haven't tried it in a compiler, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks but what is the enum ,how should i define it ?the enum should be in the same class or different?

Comment: I'd put it as a private nested class in the class the code using it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Map your String to enum, as enums can be used in switch cases. Every Enum has a **valueOf(String) method** which **converts String type to enum type**. Then you can match this enum to various cases inside switch. Only thing you need to be careful of is that String should be a valid identifier to be converted to an enum. If the string is not a valid identifier (i.e. cannot be cast to the enum type then you may end up getting **IllegalArgumentException**.

Answer (score 0):

Ankur has already suggested one way. The other way is define these as constants.
Ex - 
private static final String BOOLEAN = "1";

switch(Integer.parseInt(BOOLEAN))
case 1:...

case 2: ...

and so on.

Comment: -1 - Ewwwww! That is horrible!

Comment: What is wrong with this approach. I am only suggesting an alternative. The solution is not correct. It is upto the user to decided which option he chooses Enum vs Constants.